# Service Stack on MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I am just trying to get [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/) running under a mvc4 project.  Does the `ServiceStack.Host.Mvc` nuget package work with mvc 4.0 ?  I installed it and added the `routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");` to the routing config but it does not find the route when I go to

`/api/metadata`

and I get the error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:51681/api/metadata'.

Comment: I am also getting same issue. In chrome console it is showing that because of security issue it is not  allowing to load javascript. I don't know why?

Comment: please accept answer if your issue is solved, if issue is still there please let us know details.

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution. Whenever we are creating new asp.net mvc4 project it comes with Asp.Net Web Api. And that also having path api/. I don't you need both together, so just removed that modules using nuget package manager and it will work like anything.

If you still stuck anywhere let me know. As it is working now for me with asp.net mvc4.

Comment: Commenting this line: "WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);" from the Global.asax.cs should do the trick as well.

Comment: I just wasted like 3 hours on this crap. Someone should update the servicestack docs.

Comment: @tom.dietrich please see my answer below. Instructions are in the Readme.txt in the ServiceStack.Host.Mvc NuGet package. Anyone can update ServiceStack's wiki, you can add a comment on the aspnetwebstack project site to make this easier, thx.

Comment: @mythz I've gone ahead and added that info to the wiki page https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework . Thanks for the awesome support.

Answer (score 10):

In the [README.txt](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/README.txt) page when you install the [ServiceStack.Host.Mvc NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/) shows the instructions needed for installing ServiceStack with MVC, we've added an [extra line for support with MVC4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/README.txt#L10) since it comes bundled with a conflicting WepApi.

```
For MVC4 applications you also need to unregister WebApi, by commenting out this line:

    //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

We also dislike having to provide manual install instructions to [disable WebApi from the default install of MVC4](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1148/your-first-rest-service-with-servicestack) but unfortunately this is the best we can do at the moment with what's available.

#### The ServiceStack docs is a community wiki

If you feel there is something missing from [ServiceStack's wiki docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki), please feel free to add them, as they are a community wiki docs maintained by and are for the ServiceStack community.

#### Asking the aspnetwebstack team for an easier way to disable WebApi

We've already requested from the aspnetwebstack team if they could provide an [easier and automated way to be able to disable WebApi via Nuget](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/935), feel free to show your support of this feature by commenting on the feature request.

### Full README.txt instructions

To make the README more searchable I will repeat them here:

---

Hosting in ASP.NET MVC is very similar to hosting in any ASP.NET framework, i.e. The ServiceStack AppHost still needs to be initialized on start up in your `Global.asax.cs` (or WebActivator), e.g:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

You *MUST* register ServiceStacks '/api' path by adding the lines below to MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection) in the Global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}"); 
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" }); //Prevent exceptions for favicon
```

Place them before the current entries the method.

For MVC4 applications you also need to unregister WebApi, by commenting out this line:

```
    //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

To enable the Mini Profiler add the following lines in to MvcApplication in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
        ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.Start();
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.Stop();
}
```

For more info on the MiniProfiler see v3.09 of the https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes

The Urls for metadata page and included Services:

- /api/metadata - Auto generated metadata pages
- /api/hello - Simple Hello World Service see: http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/
- /api/todos - Simple REST Service see: http://www.servicestack.net/Backbone.Todos/
- /default.htm - Backbone.js TODO application talking to the TODO REST service at /api/todos

Comment: I've seen on some nuget packages the readme.txt popping up after installation. It might be beneficial to have this happen with the mvc package. I wasn't even aware of the readme.txt, I was following along on the side-by-side instructions on the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I new for use service stack , I use MVC 4 Application too, the answer @mythz is right.
but for

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" }); //Prevent exceptions for favicon
```

place in AppStart/RouteConfig.cs

My application running well :D