# No HTTP resource was found while calling a WCF service in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am integrating old non-MVC code into an MVC 4 project. The old code had WCF services with .SVC extensions in the root and in the API subfolder that's subject to basic authentication.

At first, posts such as (http://mysite/myservice.svc/DoCommand) to all SVC files were giving 404 errors. Then I added this:

routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*.svc(/.*)?" });

and the SVC files in the root of the site are now callable. But, the SVC files in the API sub-folder are now returning this:

```
<Error>
    <Message>
     No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://mysite/API/myservice.svc/DoCommand'.
    </Message>
</Error>
```

If I don't include the DoCommand, then I get the standard WCF info screen.

Oh, and lastly, this only happens in prod -- in development, going against localhost, all works fine.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here [Service Stack on MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361860/service-stack-on-mvc4)

The issue is that my sub-folder is called Api, which conflicts with the Api naming that comes with WebApi infrastructure that's installed with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"` in your `web.config` as detailed by [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx). See this related question: [ApiController returns 404 when ID contains period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298542/apicontroller-returns-404-when-id-contains-period/13299995#13299995)

Comment: Didn't work. http://mysite/myservice.svc/DoCommand works; http://mysite/API/myservice.svc/DoCommand doesn't work, so it's some kind of routing issue.

Comment: And, that's where it gets confusing. In RouteConfig.cs I have routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });, so I suppose MVC ignores all requests to SVC files. So, what piece of configuration outside of MVC routes to SVC files? I am not sure where to find that.