# Can I host different ServiceStack services at different URLs

Tags: web-services, configuration, servicestack

When [configuring](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework) ServiceStack, I have to specify a location (URL) at which my services will be available. E.g. when running side-by-side with WebApi:

```
<location path="svc">
 <system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
     <add path="*" type="ServiceStack..." verb="*"/>
   </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
```

Now all my ServiceStack-based services will be available at `http://server/webapp/svc/{route}`.

After reading the page about [modularizing services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services) into plugins, I was wondering: is it possible to register the service(s) contained in each plugin at a different URL (e.g. vary the `/svc/` segment of the URL per plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the configuring ServiceStack section in Hello World example on how to register [ServiceStack to run at a custom path](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#custompath).

You will also want to read the [README section and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651761/85785) if you're trying to run ServiceStack with MVC.

---

*(in response to the comment)*

There's only 1 ServiceStack AppHost in every host application, which can only be hosted on 1 root `/` or `/custompath`. All other route configurations are mapped from that `/path`. So if you register it at `/svc` you can't register a new ServiceStack AppHost from a different mount point e.g. `/svc2`. If you hosted it at root path `/` then your individual routes can be hosted at `/svc/route1`, `/svc/route2`, etc. But then you wont be able to host it side-by-side with another web fx (e.g. MVC or WebAPI).

Comment: Sorry, it seems my question was unclear. I am successfully running ServiceStack side-by-side with WebAPI (using `/api/...` for WebApi and `/svc/...` for ServiceStack). But when grouping ServiceStack services into plugins, can I register the services containied in one plugin at `/svc1/...` and the services contained in another plugin at `/svc2/...` (for example).

Comment: There's only 1 ServiceStack AppHost in every host application, which can only be hosted on 1 root / or /custompath. All other route configurations are mapped from that /path. So if you register it at `/svc` you can't register a new ServiceStack AppHost from a different mount point e.g. `/svc2`. If you hosted it at root path `/` then your individual routes can be hosted at `/svc/route1`, `/svc/route2`, etc. But then you wont be able to host it side-by-side with another web fx (e.g. MVC or WebAPI).