# ServiceStack: Having several independent/different services on one AppHost with different base paths

Tags: web-services, servicestack

I have read [one other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358885/can-i-host-different-servicestack-services-at-different-urls) that I think asks almost the same question, but I think I need to re-ask to be able to specify why this is important.

I really don't like having to start several AppHosts on different ports to be able to host different services. I could start on port 80 and have my `/greatService` and on port 81 I have `/superService` etc, but of course I'd like it all on one port, so:
`mydomain.com/greatService`
`mydomain.com/superService`

Since these services are independent of each other, I don't want a metadata page at `mydomain.com/metadata` that describes both `greatService` and `superService`. The metadata page should be at `mydomain.com/<service>/metadata` and only describe that specific service (sub-branch).

### Edit

I just realized I [suggested this in 2018](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/33333031-support-multiple-api-service-contracts-on-the-sa).

Remembering my suggestion in 2018, I am assuming this isn't possible. Then, this means that you can only host one service per AppHost, and thus per port? So, if you have several independent services, which must be a common case, the suggestion is to do what exactly? =)

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally ServiceStack Hosts can only have a single AppHost instance (per AppDomain) which is accessible via the `HostContext.AppHost` singleton.

You can't logically host/mount "multiple independent groups of Services" at different paths, you can achieve a similar result by [Modularizing your Services](http://docs.servicestack.net/modularizing-services) into different assemblies and have your `[Route]` explicitly include the prefix you want each Service hosted at, the [Routing docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#auto-route-generation-strategies) describes some options where this can be automated by implementing a custom [Auto Route Generation Strategy](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#auto-route-generation-strategies), Customizing defined Routes by [overriding GetRouteAttributes()](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#customizing-defined-routes) or [dynamically adding Route Attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#dynamically-adding-route-attributes).

My preference would be explicitly include the route you want

```
[Route("/greetService/hello")]
public class Greet { ... }

[Route("/superService/hello")]
public class Super { ... }
```

Attributes are embedded in metadata so they can only embed constants so you could have all Routes use the same prefix with something like:

```
internal static class Routes
{
    public const string Prefix = "/greetService";
}

[Route(Routes.Prefix + "/hello")]
public class Greet { ... }
```

But whilst they are grouped at different prefixes they're still grouped under the same `/metadata` page. In [Add ServiceStack Reference](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) feature if they're grouped in different namespaces you can [Include All Types within a C# namespace](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-add-servicestack-reference#include-all-types-within-a-c-namespace) with:

```
/* Options:
IncludeTypes: MyApp.ServiceModel.Greet/*
...
*/
```

The closest way to achieve what you want is to utilize the [Proxy Feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/proxy-feature) which lets you expose ServiceStack instances running on different names or ports under different prefixes, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
    matchingRequests: req => req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/techstacks"),
    resolveUrl:req => $"http://{resolve(req)}.techstacks.io"+req.RawUrl.Replace("/techstacks","/")))

Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
    matchingRequests: req => req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/marketing"),
    resolveUrl:req => "http://marketing.domain.com" + req.RawUrl.Replace("/marketing", "/")))

Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
    matchingRequests: req => req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/finance"),
    resolveUrl:req => "http://finance.domain.com" + req.RawUrl.Replace("/finance", "/")))
```

Comment: And is it technically problematic to enable ServiceStack to support my scenario? Or is it some principle, that you dont want to? I would think this scenario is a very common one: several services that are independent of each other, but should be on the same webserver (port 80 lets say). The Proxy Feature would require one ServiceStack instance per service using a unique port for reach, and one SS instance that acts as the router as per the example above?

Comment: @Ted it's fundamentally incompatible to support multiple AppHost's in the same App Domain. You'd only need a single Instance containing different ProxyFeature configurations, but if you don't want to use the proxy feature, it's best to use a reverse proxy which was designed to support use-cases like this. Have a look at our [rsync deploy](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-deploy-rsync) and [AWS ECS docker deploy](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs) which are both configured to deploy multiple instances behind an nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Ok, i see. A single instance for the PRoxyFeature, but then one SS instance per service (on a different port), right?

Comment: I dont like the approach of handling this using external things, like reverse proxy in the webservers etc, since I am not running a full webserver, Im only using .NET Framework + ServiceStack and I dont wanna complicate things with OS hacks etc. If Im just playing with the idea to have one AppHost per AppDomain, but I create new AppDomains so I can have more AppHosts. I have never ever myself dealt woth AppDomains, so not entirely sure how that would pan out.

Comment: Like: the first AppDomain/AppHost hosts the ServiceStack "router" and is placed on the std port, say 80. Then, I create a new AppDomain for each separate service and host a ServiceStack AppHost there. I would then try to route (ProxyFeature?) incoming requests to the correct AppDomain/AppHost, and thus I'd be able to keep it together all in code in one place, and still have the func I am after? Does this sound even remotly feasable? =)

Comment: @Ted I'd still recommend a reverse proxy since its purpose-specific to task, in Windows you can use [IIS + URL Rewrite](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/) or ARR. The `ProxyFeature` proxies HTTP Requests so it only works for forwarding HTTP Requests. If you want to host multiple instances in different App Domains you can execute Requests with `ServiceController.Execute*` APIs but that will only exec Services, to have it exec all HTTP reqs you'd need to exec at the `HttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler()` entry point.

Comment: Thanks for input! I dont want to get involved with IIS or any other webserver, I want this application im writing to be clean and dependent-free. When the application is on a server, I can start it and not worry about the million things that comes with IIS installation etc. The proxy feature will be enough then, as this is a webservice over http?

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean with _"but that will only exec Services, to have it exec all HTTP reqs you'd need to exec at the ...."_?

Comment: @Ted `ProxyFeature` essentially does the same job as a reverse proxy except it does the HTTP Proxying in .NET which allows C# flexibility in routing/transformations and doesn't need any infrastructure deps. Are you running Self Hosted HttpListener Apps? Because it may support hosting on same port at different paths, so you may be able to run multiple instances on different `Config.HandlerFactoryPath` on the same port.

Comment: @Ted `ServiceController.Execute*` APIs only exec ServiceStack Services is only relevant if you wanted to try invoke requests "in code" through App Domains, it doesn't apply to HTTP proxies.

Comment: Thansk again Mythz, superb support, as always. So, `ServiceController.Execute` will pass in both the DTO and IRequest, so whats the difference from using a proxy? With the DTO and the IRequest, I have everything I need, right?

Comment: Q: _"Are you running Self Hosted HttpListener Apps?"_ Well, I am running instances of the `AppSelfHostBase` (I inherit from that) and eventually do a `_serviceStackHost.Start(urls);`. So, not sure if that is a yes or no =)

Comment: `AppSelfHostBase` on .NET Framework is a self-hosted HTTP Listener so you can try to see if you can host different instances on the same port but at different paths (set with `SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "greetService" })`). Already described differences with `ServiceController.Execute*`, it only executes ServiceStack Services (similar to the Service Gateway), whilst the HTTP Proxy proxies all HTTP requests, i.e. inc all other resources SS serves.