# Setting up Web.config to work Side-by-Side with ASP.NET MVC 4 - Location Tag not resolving value "api"

Tags: servicestack

I checked out [Run servicestack side by side with another web framework](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework).

When I add the location tag the "api" is unresolved...what do I need to do to get the location tag to be aware of "api"?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure you follow the [README.txt instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651761/85785) for running ServiceStack in ASP.NET MVC. 
ServiceStack automatically infers the handler path based on the `<location>` tag, if there's more than one or it has some other issue inferring, it can be explicitly set in `Config.ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath`, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { 
    ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude but you need to consolidate all this documentation.  Include this info in your related wiki pages.  Honestly I feel the wiki needs organization and there is a crapload of documentation that you put in your replies that are formatted well enough to be put in wiki pages as well

Comment: I am not quite sure why you would bury that kind of info in readme files.  That's old hat.  Put configuration instructions in your wiki

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Agreed, I've just added this info to the [Mvc Integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) page.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict like I said before, ServiceStack's is undergoing significant re-factoring and `master` in alpha and not for public use. While everything still builds for me and tests still pass in CI, it will be frequently unstable until its in beta. You're likely mixing v3 with v4 dlls which are technically incompatible. The release on NuGet is off the `v3` branches of each project, that's what you should checkout if you want to build from src. Any contribs should be done to `v3-fixes` only - see [Contributing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Contributing) docs for more info.

Comment: So what do i pull down exactly for v3?  None of the structure up there is obvious or separated between versions except for a couple folders inside the main ServiceStack folder that have a v4 in the name but that is only a couple that say this

Comment: NuGet only brings down dlls. I want the source for v3 not dlls.

Comment: if I were to browse the GitHub site itself, where can I see the v-3 branch? (I'm not talking about uising Git locally, I should somehow be able to see this v-3 branch that the contrib page is referring to as well without git)

Comment: "ServiceStack's is undergoing significant re-factoring and master in alpha and not for public use"  What exactly are you referring to, what did you download form the site and try compiling.  What is not for public use, what code in your repos?   I need specifics, you are not clear enough here....you're making the assumption that I know all about your stack and how you are managing this v3 to v4 codebase.

Comment: You know right now I have NO specifics from you mythz. You "think" you are giving me specifics but only giving me generalizations and links..which are not helping.  We truly want to use the API (boss & team), and I am trying my best not to throw my PC against the wall and bitch more, but you're not laying this out & stating wha's going on.  I pulled down the major Stack downloads on your Wiki landing page and at this point, I don't know what's up or down.

Comment: extending on my last comment (Because of char limit):    What Nuget command and where/when??  What CAN I download on your wiki download page for v3 and where?  Where is the separation of v3 vs. v4 code? wher can I view the v-3 branch ON the GitHub?

Comment: and does this statement in your docs still stand? "GitHub has disabled its download feature so currently NuGet is the best way to get ServiceStack published releases"  What does that mean?  I --am-- able to download the source so is that sentence outdated in your docs?  just checking.

Comment: Should I just tell my boss forget it?  It is looking that way, might have to roll our own if I can't even get this stuff straight from you.