# Compile Errors Galore - Cannot build some ServiceStack solutions download from GitHub

Tags: servicestack

This is just odd.

I'm getting a build error in `ServiceStack.Text` after just bringing down [the latest build](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) from GitHub.

```
if (endpointUrl.IsNullOrEmpty() || !endpointUrl.StartsWith("http"))
 return null;

Error   1   No overload for method 'IsNullOrEmpty' takes 0 arguments
ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\Messaging\ClientFactory.cs 10  18
ServiceStack.Common
```

I'm also getting bunch of other build errors:

Error   35  'int' does not contain a definition for 'Times' and no extension method 'Times' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ServiceStack.Redis\src\ServiceStack.Redis\Messaging\RedisMqServer.cs    192 37  ServiceStack.Redis

[image]

and after downloading the [ServiceStack branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack), I even tried opening ServiceStack-master\src\ServiceStack.sln and tried to build and it's totally broken:

[image]

I don't know what's going on here, there can't possibly be this many build errors if any right?  I pray not but it seems as such.

**Purpose of this post, what I'm asking about and need help clarifying and resolving (mythz???)**

I need input from ServiceStack here on the following:

**1)** are the builds really this broken?  Am I imagining this?

**2)** The branch stucture on GitHub is all over the place meaning I'm finding dup project folders all over and I do not know what this ServiceStack branch is as in it's src folder has a ton of projects there, different versions, as well as doesn't have projects like ServiceStack.Text, etc. so I don't know what's going on here.  I want to use the basic core of service stack but there's like repeated stuff everywhere overall on GitHub.  I need ServiceStack to clear all this up for me.

Here is my code, so you can see for yourself, it doesn't build.

- [This one](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6FDE5kMwYTlaVhRQWw3eE9KQ1k/edit?usp=sharing) **won't build** in terms of the ServiceStack projects - it's my solution in which I'm simply trying to include the ServiceStack projects I need along with my own projects that are using ServiceSTack.  All I did was downoad those individual projects from https://github.com/ServiceStack then added them to my solution and made sure that any references to each other were now Project references, no longer binary..I removed the binary refs and readded them as project refs.  So for example ServiceStack.Common depends on ServiceStack.Text but it was referencing it via binary so I removed it and readded the reference to ServiceStack.Text as a project ref now because in the end we plan on being able to look at and work with the base Stack code.  The errors I posted above are happening in this Solution for ServiceStack related projects.
- [This one](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6FDE5kMwYTlQ0owXzBrNEptZlU/edit?usp=sharing) **won't build** - it's a download of the ServiceStack branch master (originally folder name is ServiceStack-master, I removed the -master)

**UPDATE**: yes I confirmed it's a bad build checked in on the GitHub site (refering to the ServiceStack branch master right above here).  I had to remove unused using statements that were causing the build to fail and one of these was a dup using statement causing part of the build failure.  I am surprised at this...this stuff should build and people should be checking in code that BUILDS successfully!  common!  Yes mythz, any dev trying to consume your API would be pissed that there are so many build erros all the time, I can't even get our protype going because this is not the only solution that won't build.  First we had the Examples solution all breaking and now the core.  I'm willing to fix these if I can but I honestly can't believe it's been a mountain to try to even use this API because of these checked in builds that are failing.

[image]

- [This one](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6FDE5kMwYTleDBBc3laNUpIc0k/edit?usp=sharing) **Will build** because it was Nuget down, so ServiceStack is referencing other layers via binary references in the lib folder so this builds...probably builds here because someone has a **working** set of builds across all core projects but the stuff on the site for download is not the same revision and broken when you try to use them as project references (source code)??  Just my conclusion as it's only building IF you are using binary references to the lib folder.  We want the source, not the binaries to work inside our solution so this is a brick wall for me

Comment: I have not vote to close anything, but if you ask the users,  the "just be polite"  and be  calm, it  is a nice advice for everybody, especially in OSS.

Comment: The  will fix it very fast, but if you want super fast, remove the references "using ServiceStack.Common;" and "using ServiceStack.Common.Support;" Also remove the double line "using ServiceStack.Model;" Then the ServiceStack solution will be compiled. (time 5 min,  much less than the time to write your   question. You could inform about the problem with few words.)

Comment: @Stefan it's not always easy to be polite or calm, it's the nature of software development especially when you cannot get stuff that should build built.  Any dev would be annoyed and I feel it's ok to express that to some level...I think people are too worried about tone in this forum TBH.

Comment: @stefan the problem is you don't know what's v3 vs. v4 up on their main GitHub site to begin with, there is no clear path to take.  I don't see a repository on that site either that explicitely says v3

Comment: we're starting to think ServiceStack is not for us due to all these "in flux" issues as well as documentation is sparatic (core documentation is on the wiki, in stackoverfow, in readme fiels) and besides the last single relaese (v3), the current stuff that's up there is a black box to everyone.  Not getting a good feeling from this nor is my boss on it.  The code seems solid, but if we can't figure out what's what in terms of versions, builds that continuously break, etc. then we may just roll our own...eat the cost for consistency and maintainability

Comment: since there has only been one release it tells me this open source which means we landed on this project that JUST started up and I bet this API hasn't been used that much yet (tested and proven, bugs resolved, etc.) so that I was not aware of, one release so v2 and v1 must have been "creating" the initial beta of this open source API

Comment: you are free to not use it, but this API is working 3 years now, it behaves very well. As a user I know that  from my experience.  Good bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of big changes happening on master right now - it will be unstable for a while.

I suggest you branch from the v3-fixes tag or pull the references from nuget.

Comment: ok but the snapshot doesn't have some projects like .Text, etc. so it's probably using assembly refs.  I want all the projects though (source code) so umm..

Comment: I don't want just the refs, I want working source ..all of it for v3.  The release here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/releases doesn't have all of the projects in it either.

Comment: Then you should branch from the v3-snapshot tag in ServiceStack.Text, ServiceStack.OrmLite, and other projects as well

Comment: how do you do that?  I only see a v3 in the releases tab.

Answer (score 1):

@CoffeeAddict

Yesterday, the  mythz answered about these problems in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008011/setting-up-web-config-to-work-side-by-side-with-asp-net-mvc-4-location-tag-not)

"@CoffeeAddict like I said before, ServiceStack's is undergoing significant re-factoring and master in alpha and not for public use. While everything still builds for me and tests still pass in CI, it will be frequently unstable until its in beta. You're likely mixing v3 with v4 dlls which are technically incompatible. The release on NuGet is off the v3 branches of each project, that's what you should checkout if you want to build from src. Any contribs should be done to v3-fixes only - see Contributing docs for more info. – mythz 9 hours ago"

Comment: that didn't tell me a thing...and I replied to that...it's not clear.  Today I finally found that 1 release sitting there v3, which he could have simply pointed me to.  I need specifics, not generalizations.  But then again, that v3 branch does not have full source code for ServiceStack.Text, and some others in that build.  I need those too so it's still an underlying problem.  It's prob using assembly refs for the source code projects I do not see in the root of that v3 build.

Comment: I've suggested that the stack site be organized more.  They need to make clear what's v4 code and separate that out.

Comment: Be patient please.  It is OSS, you don't pay anything. Volunteers spend their valuable time, eager to make something really good. I have not seen such dedication from  product teams of software giants  to whom we pay   a lot of money.  If you don't understand it and you don't appreciate their dedication, you are free to  not use it.

Comment: I don't buy the "we don't pay anything" excuse.  It's a product no matter which way you wanna dice it (free, not free) and businesses are are relying on these open source frameworks.  If you're gonna expose an API, it better a) work, b) build, c) be consistent.  If anyone decides to use your API (meaning if I were to post one) I'd know they'd expect certain things...basic function and consistency.  So I don't buy this free excuse.  Sure there can be issues but not stuff like builds.  Codebase should be discoverable, CI should be in place, and documentation updated and consistent and central

Comment: I'm not taking it personal Stefan, so you don't need to either.  It's no biggie man.  I was frustrated, stated that fact and moving on....

Answer (score 0):

well looks like when I had downloaded all the stack branches, at the time earlier today contributors had checked in broken builds. Fabulous.

I just got latest early this morning, and appears people must have fixed the build and checked some stuff back in for various core projects. Now it builds.

Suggestion to mythz, get CI in place NOW. Don't wait for v4. This cost me a freakin day of trying various things to get this stuff to build and the problems were across several projects. This shouldn't happen, setup CI please. It's 2am and nobody using this project should have to deal with it.

I will contribute but first I had to get a full build to work! Not too happy as no dev would be wasting an entire day getting ServiceStack to build.

Answer (score -3):

```
To compile v3: 
Would someone with true knowledge post PROPER instructions on compiling v4 or v3? I had no luck with the build.bat files for v3 or v4, and opening solutions will not compile for most. 

git clone servicestack, servicestack.text, redis, ormlite

make a new directory and copy from under src so you have these:

ServiceStack
ServiceStack.Client
ServiceStack.Common
ServiceStack.Interfaces
ServiceStack.OrmLite
ServiceStack.Redis
ServiceStack.Server
ServiceStack.Text

open csproj for ServiceStack.Interfaces ... right click properties, go to the signing tab, click the combo, new, type in your own signing pfx, I used servicestackInterfaces.pfx (doesn't matter) and make up a password.
Compiles fine, since it has not much referenced.

saved solution as ServiceStackV3 in folder C:\2015\SSv3compile

add csproj ServiceStack.Text, set signature, compiles ok

add csproj ServiceStack.Common, set signature, remove references, add references using solution for interface, text, compiles ok

add csproj ServiceStack.Client, set signature, remove references, add references  using solution for interface, text, compiles ok

add csproj ServiceStack, set signature, remove references, add references  using solution for client, common, interface, text, compiles ok

add csproj ServiceStack.OrmLite, set signature, remove references, add references  using solution for common, interface, text, compiles ok

add csproj ServiceStack.Redis, set signature, remove references, add references  using solution for common, interface, text, compiles ok

add csproj ServiceStack.ServiceStack.Server, set signature, remove references, add references  using solution for Servicestack, ServiceStack.Client, ServiceStack.Common, ServiceStack.Interface, ServiceStack.Text, ServiceStack.Ormlite, ServiceStack.Redis

compiles ok

have some more trouble compiling the tests...
```

and finding so many tweaks and changes which are for me maddening to find 
(endless agentransack searching for "namespace ISomethinMissing" in *.cs

... there seems to be namespace ServiceStack with cs code contained in projects other than Servicestack...
isn't that VERY improper? (now you require both DLLs? why not one?)
    whatever...its free and works for what I wanted.

```
looks like there is some code leakage from v4...   

after getting my head around v3, not sure I want to buy v4 - I will probably buy it in the future, I expect, and hope someday I can just clone and compile from the solution
```

ANyway, I love servicestack and have been 
replacing old webservices 
and the config nightmares of WCF with great happiness...

I say it is well worth the initial hassle.

I put this all in code block because I found the editor wouldn't accept this simple text when it was in a numbered list. whatever.